# PC runs on UPS but stops on main line why?

Tags: boot, desktop-computer

I am getting a strange problem with my pc , I am running it through a 600va UPS .My UPS is new just 10 days old .

the problem is that my PC sometimes starts rebooting again and again as a cycle and sometimes it just works all fine so its very difficult to seek real issue when it works all good sometime and bad sometime.one day before yesterday I switched main power off so putting it on UPS backup and it worked fine but as soon as I put power on it went off randomly ,even though CPU case showing power light and it was linked with UPS,then I again switched off my main power and it restarted PC through UPS backup ?

My system configuration is :

- Intel core i3 4130 processor
- Dual boot win7/Ubuntu 18.04 (64 bit both)
- Intel dh87mc ATX motherboard
- corsair vs450 PSU (input 100-240 VAC)
- no graphic card (Intel integrated graphics),4GB corsair vengeance RAM
- main line (240 v) found fluctuations checked by electrician (238-241v)
  I tried to run it without UPS and it works fine but the problem of reboot cycle happens often ,with UPS or without UPS

I consulted at service center ,took my CPU there and strange but it worked all fine there ,I tried to use it with multiple windows open at chrome etc still it worked fine . system engineer told it looks voltage problem in your area as your motherboard look fine .

I came home it worked fine for sometime then again same reboot cycle problem.

I am not getting what real problem is ,I bought new UPS but still getting same problem ,any possible causes or suggestions?

[here](https://youtu.be/BOnC7ugz0LQ) is the video of reboot cycle

I did one thing plugged PC in main line extension and it worked fine then I again put it back to UPS and it worked fine for around 20 minutes and then same reboot cycle ! No clue what's happening ,any suggestions ?

thank you !

Comment: What's the line voltage and what's the input voltage of your power supply? For example, if the line voltage is 120V, but your PSU expects 230/240V, it might work through the UPS if the UPS accepts any (100-240V) input voltage and has an output voltage of 230/240V.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser.  Please restrict each Question to just one question and don't give confusing extra details ("HD which not properly working giving warning for data backup").  If possible please say fewer details, and use good spelling, capitalization, and punctuation.

Comment: Do you have a graphics card as well as the components listed in the original question?  If so, there might be too much power draw for the PSU.

Comment: @ChristopherHostage Oh sorry I will remember your suggestions further ,about graphics card no I don't have any dedicated graphic card though there is an inbuilt graphic support for my intel motherboard/processor .

Comment: @ChristopherHostage   updated my question kindly have a relook ,thank you ,apology if I was unclear before :(

Comment: Can you run the computer in a different place (a different neighborhood altogether), that would rule out your house's power supply (it could be the local substation too). Have you tested the PSU, does "bios config" confirm the voltages are all right, and stable? Some bios have a sensitive "switch off to prevent power fluctuations damaging components", you could turn that off but you might break the system.

Comment: @pbhj i went to intel warranty centre ,I used my CPU there for around 20-25 minutes and it worked all good ,that center was in other area different from my location  .Actually I am not getting the exact issue ,look sequence is mainline >> UPS >> PC now what happens is when I put mainline off it starts the PC and works fine but as soon as I switch on the main line it shuts/blanks the PC immediately and the strange thing is it doesn't happen everytime ,sometimes it works fine and sometimes it doesn't ,can you suggest any possible causes ? thank you !

Comment: During that immediate shuts/blanks of PC it shows power LED (blue one )on of the cabinet but it doesn't show any HardDrive LED (red one),it does shutdown in a blink when this happen ,but not like as it does when shutting down PC properly ,any idea  what real problem is ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was indeed problem with my power supply ,I was skepticle about it initially because I was using Corsair vs450 ,so if anyone faces such problem always verify your PC's power supply first !

Answer (score 2):

You probably have power fluctuations in your house.
Running on the UPS "smooths" the power up, as the UPS is built to withstand
such fluctuations.

If you cannot find the source of the fluctuations, or this is a problem
with the electricity supplier to your house, run the computer only on
UPS. Too high fluctuations may damage the computer.

There are power detectors that can analyze the power for fluctuations.
You could also contact your electricity company and ask for advice.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93231/discussion-on-answer-by-harrymc-pc-runs-on-ups-but-stops-on-main-line-why).

Comment: @harrymc During my research over the random boot issue related meltdown spectre issue in intel CPU , kindly refer the following article https://www.cnbc.com/2018/01/18/intel-patches-are-causing-computers-to-randomly-restart.html

Comment: @harrymc  and Intel's official confirmation here https://newsroom.intel.com/news/root-cause-of-reboot-issue-identified-updated-guidance-for-customers-and-partners/.       So is my random reboot is due to Intel's CPU flaw ??? My CPU belongs to haswell series which got affected as the previous article states.